# How to get Network Emulator for Windows Toolkit to increase latency for pinging 127.0.0.1?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, latency

I'm making a multiplayer game and I need to test it in simulated environment with packet loss, high latencies, packet reordering, etc. I'm using Network Emulator for Windows Toolkit for this purpose. However I can't get it to work for loopback packets. For instance when I do "ping google.com" I get increased latency but when I do "ping 127.0.0.1" - latency is under 1ms, so I think NEWT is not intercepting these packets. Do you have any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: I think this belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

If you install VMWare player you can create a "remote" server with its own network interface.  You probably aren't going to be able to intercept the loopback address reliably on Windows, but more importantly what you are trying to do is not a good test: it doesn't tell you how the game will run in a realistic setting, with two computers and two OSs interacting.  With a VM and network emulator you have something closer to reality.